# Capitalization of acronym in header

Tags: glossaries, fancyhdr, capitalization

I'm using the short form of an acronym defined using the glossaries package in a section title. To properly capitalize the title, I'm using the `\Acs` macro. This works fine for the actual section name. In the header, however, the acronym is not properly capitalized.

Here's an MWE of the problem

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[
  acronym,
  shortcuts
]{glossaries}

\fancypagestyle{mystyle}{
  \fancyhead[RO]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
}
\pagestyle{mystyle}

\newacronym{MWE}{minimal-WE}{minimal working example}

\begin{document}

\section{This is a \Acs{MWE}}

\end{document}
```

and the output it creates
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with `\nouppercase`. That is a sort of <strike>hack</strike> ingenious and convenient feature which *disables* `MakeUpperCase`. Since `glossaries` is *using* `MakeUpperCase` to capitalise the "m", it fails.

The probably "correct" way to handle this if you want to make extensive use of acronyms in section headers is to redefine the relevant sectionmark directly so that it does not include `MakeUpperCase`:

```
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\thesection.\quad#1}
```

And then **lose** the `\nouppercase` from your header definition. As the `fancyhdr` manual notes, this won't necessarily save you from those sections like bibliography which need it. You may have to do that for any relevant section headings, if more than one contains acronyms. Don't quote me on the precise spacing required to emulate the standard definition.

The easiest thing to do if it's a one off would, I am afraid, simply be to use your fingers to type the actual text you want in the heading, rather than using any acronym there!

Comment: Thanks for the info. I opted for the manual route. Considering that I also got hyperref-related warnings from using acronyms in section names, I had wrapped them in `\textorpdfstring` anyway so it really didn't save me much typing to begin with ;)